# Nextjs creating a url that only processes code with no view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a new site using NextJS, the issue i am having is in regards to a password reset verification endpoint.

When a user triggers a password reset, it goes to the API, does all the processing and then returns them to the NextJS frontend at `/verifyreset`, which saves a code into localstorage, does a small bit of processing and then forwards them onto another page.

The issue is that there is a Default layout wrapping the component in my _app.js like so;

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <DefaultLayout><Component {...pageProps} /></DefaultLayout>
    );
}
```

which means that the layout shows on the `/verifyreset` endpoint, and I only want that endpoint to process data.

Is there any way around this? to have an endpoint that can access localstorage but not be a 'page' so to speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did partially understand your question, it would have been clear if you had attached more code snippets in the question.

Anyway, from your statement below:

> When a user triggers a password reset, it goes to the API, does all
> the processing and then returns them to the NextJS frontend at
> /verifyreset, which saves a code into localstorage, does a small bit
> of processing and then forwards them onto another page.

what I understood is:

1. User triggers a password reset [lets say from PageA]
2. API is invoked; some processing happen
3. API then, redirects user to /verifyreset page [lets say it PageB]
4. Navigating to the page, information is saved into localstorage
5. Once that is completed, user is redirected to another page [lets say it PageC]

Correct me if I am wrong, so your question is, how could you actually skip users to view /verifyreset page but do the things like save to localstorage and other background operations.

**Answer 1:** The api is being invoked from PageA (see 1). Instead of the api redirecting user to /verifyreset page on the frontend, send some data (JSON or XML) to the calling function (in PageA components..). Based on that data, do the processing and once every thing is complete, redirect the user to PageC. [no need to worry about PageB i.e. /verifyreset page]. Please find the code snippet below:

```
**API End Point**

async resetPassword(req, res) {
try {
  const model = model.body || {};
  let data = await PasswordBusiness.reset(model);
  //data needs to have information that you require on frontend
  return res.json({success: true, data: data});
} catch (error) {
  return res.json({success: false, error: error});
}
}


** Frontend - pageA **


import Router from 'next/router';

const resetPassword = (model) => {
  callApiEndPoint(model).then(data) {
   // do what you want to do with data

   //finally navigate to page c
   Router.push('url-to-page-c');

  });
};


return <button onClick={resetPassword}> Reset </button>
```

**Answer 2:** If you require redirecting to the page any how from the API [I think you don't necessary require this], once operation/processing is completed on API end, redirect the user directly to the pageC with some query params with data (if they are not security vulnerable data). e.g. /pagec?token=sometokens&otherinfos=otherinfos and do things on pageC itself. Once completed, remove the query string from the page without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `/verifyreset` at the api folder.

This is what `Next.js` said in their documentation :

```
Any file inside the folder pages/api is mapped to /api/* and will be treated as an API endpoint instead of a page.
```

Reference : https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: I didn't think the API routes had access to localstorage?

Comment: @CodeSauce I haven't tried it yet but if that's true, maybe change the process to do something at API endpoint and return to any page then save your localStorage here.

Can you provide some code? It may help me to understand big picture of it.